# Разделить строку на символы при этом убрать из нее знаки препинания

Tags: python, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста, как разделить строку на список элементов при этом чтобы в список не вошли знаки препинания.
Строка для примера: А роза упала на лапу Азора

Comment: пробел это знак припинания?

Comment: Вики утверждает что да.

Comment: а у питона нет. `c not in string.punctuation + string.whitespace`  если пробелы надо убрать

Comment: Вариант решения с регулярным выражением: [`re.findall(r'[^\W_]', s)`](https://ideone.com/1EEu91)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew только тут "оставить буквы цифры пробелы и убрать пробел"

Comment: @eri `[^\W_]` найдёт только цифры и буквы.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, это я и написалю да вот задание другое... а так просто занудствую

Comment: Мне кажется, надо ждать уточнений от автора дальнейших, потому что иначе спорить можно долго, например, ответы со `string.punctuation` не удаляют из строки многоточие (`\u2026`), я думаю, в юникоде можно ещё много символов найти, которые выглядят как знак препинания и отсутсвтуют в `string.punctuation`, а тут ещё версия питона не указана, что тоже может быть поводом для дискуссий

Comment: Да никто не спорит. Просто раз это решение [сработало](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f?noredirect=1#comment1624553_968835),  я просто решил добавить более короткий аналог уже отмеченного решения на основе регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне больше с фильтром нравится, `for .. if ..`  читается тяжело.

```
import string
s = "А роза упала на лапу Азора"
cs = list(filter( lambda x: x not in string.punctuation + string.whitespace, s))
```

`string.punctuation` и `string.whitespace` это простые наборы символов:

```
!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

и

```
 \t\n\r\x0b\x0c
```

Comment: Вот это решение сработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```
import string

s = 'А роза упала на лапу Азора'
cs = [c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation]
```

Comment: Это тоже самое, что я применял list() к строке. Он создает массив где отдельными элементами массива являются строки. Видимо в методе string.punctuation пробел не является знаком пунктуации.

Comment: @mamba9999 не то же, ещё знаки препинания убираются.

Comment: В моем случае тоже самое. Все равно спасибо. Буду знать.

Comment: @mamba9999 в смысле? Знаки препинания не убираются?

Comment: Ну в этой строке есть только пробелы. Я про это.

Comment: @mamba9999 это всё философия. Ответ отличный, а набор символов можно дополнить или заменить на свой.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
import re
from string import punctuation, whitespace

text = 'А роза упала на лапу Азора'
items = re.findall('[^' + punctuation + whitespace + ']', text)
print(items)
```

Comment: "убрать знаки припинания" и "оставить только буквы" - разные условия

Comment: @eri, согласен. Исправил :)